# Submenu Not Working in .NET 6 Razor Page Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0, submenu

I am testing a simple .NET 6 web app (razor pages only, no MVC), and run into problem with submenu.

**TEST ENVIRONMENT**:

OS: Windows 11

IDE: Visual Studio 2022

Bootstrap V4

Browser: Chrome

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

After creating the web app, I added a dropdown menu item called "Services" with 3 submenu items (see _layout.cshtml file content at the end of this post).  Each submenu maps to a razor page.

When I tested the app, the dropdown menu did not work at all, all razor pages were working fine when tested with urls. Previously, I was able to use same method to implement submenu items within a .NET 5 MVC app.

**QUESTION:**

1. The submenu implementation followed the example at the bootstrap website.  What is wrong in my _layout.cshtml file?
2. Are there differences in the way of how _layout.cshtml works in .NET 5 and .NET 6?

**TEST CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RazorSubmenu</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Font Icon CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/RazorSubmenu.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">RazorSubmenu</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item  dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-page="/Services/Item1">Item 1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-page="/Services/Item3">Item 2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="" asp-page="/Services/Item3">Item 3</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - RazorSubmenu - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question has nothing with C# or Razor, most likely you're missing a script file or css file. Inspect the page when you see it if there are files that cannot be loaded.

Comment: @riffnl:  After created the Web app in VS 2022, I only did 2 things:  (1) Added submenu options in _layout.cshtml (2) created 3 razor pages under \pages\services folder.  I did not add any css or js script.

Comment: @riffnl:  I checked all css & js files listed in the _layout.cshtml file.  Two .js files are listed near the end of _layout file.   They are: (1) "~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", (2) "~/js/site.js".  Both files are found under the wwwroot folder.

Comment: @riffnl:  Two css files are listed near the end of </head> tag.  The first one is "~/css/site.css" that exists under the "wwwroot".  The 2nd one is ""~/RazorSubmenu.styles.css”. It is not under the "wwwroot".  It is located at "RazorSubmenu\obj\Debug\net6.0\scopedcss\bundle\RazorSubmenu.styles.css".  So far,  I have not seen any css or js file missing.  Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

Comment: was not online when these questions were posted, but for future readers: if the files are *not* in wwwroot they will not be automatically copied to the iis(-express) folder for reading, so your browser cannot read the files. You do not need jsdelivr (or similar) but you need to reference your files correctly within your project - when you open a debugging browser window and use the dev window you'll see which files could not be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add js reference by local file. `.NET 5` default Bootstrap version is `Bootstrap v4.x`, but `.NET 6` default version is `Bootstrap v5.x`.

So you need download Bootstrap version 4.x or just use jsDelivr:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the  problem of bootstrap version mismatch.  Since our app may have users who still use older version of browsers, we need to keep using bootstrap v4. x I downloaded v4.6.1 and use it in my program.  The dropdown menu is working now.

Comment: Could you change your comments as the solution to my question? Then, I will mark it as resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @bedrock, updated. Pls check.

Comment: I did changed my program to use jsdelivr.net for all bootstrap files.  Thanks for your assistance